# Removing IDs under specific conditions in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataset and I need to remove IDs entirely that are flagged before a certain date and beyond. I am having trouble getting a start on this one.

df =

```
 ID      Date        Flagged 
 101    6/4/2023       0
 101    7/23/2023      0
 102    4/28/2023      1
 102    5/2/2023       1
 102    6/30/2023      1
 102    7/11/2023      1
 103    6/23/2023      1
 103    7/12/2023      1
 104    4/17/2023      0 
 104    5/12/2023      1
 104    6/17/2023      1
 104    7/22/2023      1
```

I would like to remove the IDs all together that are `Flagged` before May 1 2023.
I tried

```py
today = datetime.datetime.today()
x_days = today - dt(days=90)`
filtered_df = df{(df['Flagged'] == 1) & (df['Date' >= x_days)]
```

When I run this I still have IDs that I would like to have completely removed. Below is a desired output:

df =

```
 ID      Date      Flagged 
 103   6/23/2023     1
 103   7/12/2023     1
 104   5/12/2023     1
 104   6/17/2023     1
 104   7/22/2023     1
```

Any help with this would be great thank you!

Comment: How can you have `Flagged=0` in the output with the condition `(df['Flagged'] == 1)` ?

Comment: Thank you for catching that I didn't mean to have those added I will fix edit that.

Comment: @Coding_Nubie - Why is ID 101 removed?

Comment: Why does your desired output not have 5-2-23 in it? It is both flagged and did not come before 5-1-23

Comment: @not_speshal I onlu care about flagged rows

Comment: @MichaelS. Because they had a record flagged before 5/1 so I want to ignore that ID all together.

Comment: please also mention your expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use boolean indexing:

```
#convert to datetime if needed
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"],format="%m/%d/%Y")

#get flagged IDs to ignore
flagged = df[df["Flagged"].eq(1)&df["Date"].lt(pd.Timestamp.today()-pd.DateOffset(90))]

>>> df[~df["ID"].isin(flagged["ID"])&df["Flagged"].eq(1)]

     ID       Date  Flagged
6   103 2023-06-23        1
7   103 2023-07-12        1
9   104 2023-05-12        1
10  104 2023-06-17        1
11  104 2023-07-22        1
```

Comment: Careful with this answer. OP wants all dates flagged before May 1, 2023 and this answer relies on the current date. If OP runs this code a month from now, or even a few days, they will not get their desired results.

Comment: This seemed to have worked thank you

Comment: @MichaelS - OP has used in `today - dt(days=90)` in their post. Same logic.

Comment: Yes but OP specified a specific date, not a specific amount of time from when the code was run. Just because OP tried `today - dt(days=90)` does not mean that that is the correct approach.

Comment: @MichaelS. - I figured OP wanted a dynamic solution. Hard-coding the date is easy if that's what they need.

Comment: Agreed and I agree your answer is correct, I just want OP to realize the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
# Convert 'Date' column to datetime format (to be sure)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

# Define cutoff date
cutoff_date = datetime(2023, 5, 1)

# Create a mask to filter IDs flagged before the cutoff date
mask = (df['Flagged'] == 1) & (df['Date'] >= cutoff_date)

# Get the list of IDs to be removed
ids_to_remove = df.loc[mask, 'ID'].unique()

# Filter out the IDs from the DataFrame
filtered_df = df[~df['ID'].isin(ids_to_remove)]
```

Answer (score 1):

First find any IDs that have been flagged before your specified date then only find the values that have both been flagged and do not have one of the bad ids:

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime 

# create dataframe:
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'ID' : [101, 101, 102, 102, 102, 102, 103, 103, 104, 104, 104, 104],
     'Date' : ['6/4/2023' ,'7/23/2023','4/28/2023','5/2/2023' ,'6/30/2023','7/11/2023','6/23/2023','7/12/2023','4/17/2023','5/12/2023','6/17/2023','7/22/2023'],
     'Flagged' : [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]})

# Convert dates
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format = '%m/%d/%Y')

# Find bad IDs (ones that had a flag before specific date)
bad_ids = df[(df.Flagged.eq(1)) & (df.Date < datetime.datetime(2023, 5, 1))].ID.unique()

# Find all values that are flagged and do not have a bad ID
df[(df.Flagged.eq(1)) & ~(df.ID.isin(bad_ids))]
```

Output:

```
    ID  Date        Flagged
6   103 2023-06-23  1
7   103 2023-07-12  1
9   104 2023-05-12  1
10  104 2023-06-17  1
11  104 2023-07-22  1
```